# Android/Java: <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"> doesn't work anymore in WebView

Tags: java, android, html, android-camera

How can I open the camera from a webview directly in html to take a picture or pick up a gallery photo with android? It seems that the

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

doesn't work anymore...

Here is my code:

main class:

```
     @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    
                if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    return;
                }
    
                Uri[] results = null;
    
                // Check that the response is a good one
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data == null) {
                        // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                        if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = data.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
                mFilePathCallback = null;
    
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    return;
                }
    
                if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
    
                    if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                        return;
    
                    }
    
                    Uri result = null;
    
                    try {
                        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
    
                            result = null;
    
                        } else {
    
                            // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                            result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
    
                    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                    mUploadMessage = null;
    
                }
            }
    
            return;
        }
    
        private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            // Create an image file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
          //  File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    
    
       //     File storageDir = new File(LoginActivity.getAppContext().getFilesDir() + "/NTA/temp");
    
            if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                storageDir.mkdir();
            }
    
            File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    storageDir      /* directory */
            );
            return imageFile;
        }
    
...
    view = findViewById(R.id.vieweb);
    
    
    
    
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            view.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            view.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            view.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
            view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            view.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
            view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            view.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
            view.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
            view.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
            view.getSettings().setAppCachePath(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            view.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            view.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
    
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            view.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
            view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            view.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
            view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            view.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    
    
            bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem Item) {
                    //put initialization to not initialize the bottom navigation bar
                    newBottomNav.updated = 0;
                    newBottomNav.initialization = 1;
    
                    view.loadUrl("file:///" + LoginActivity.getAppContext().getFilesDir() + "/NTA/APP/index.html?" + MenuMap.get(Item.toString()) + "&" + codeLangue);
    
                    return true;
                }
            });
    
            //TEST BEGIN
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            view.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OFF);
            view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            view.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
            view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            view.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
            view.getSettings().supportZoom();
    
            view.loadUrl(url);
    
            view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    // do your handling codes here, which url is the requested url
                    // probably you need to open that url rather than redirect:
                    if ( url.contains(".pdf")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
                        try{
                            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            //user does not have a pdf viewer installed
                        }
                    } else {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                    }
                    return false; // then it is not handled by default action
                }
    
    
                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    
                    Log.e("error",description);
                }
    
    
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {        //show progressbar here
    
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    //hide progressbar here
    
                }
    
            });
            view.setWebChromeClient(new LocalNav.ChromeClient());

        }
    }


    //TEST BEGIN
    public class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    
        // For Android 5.0
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePath;
    
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                     Log.e("check", "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }
    
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
    
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
    
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }
    
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
    
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
    
            return true;
    
        }
    
        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
    
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            String path = LoginActivity.getAppContext().getFilesDir() + "/NTA/temp";
            //File storageDir = new File(path);
    
        //    File imageStorageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    , "Temp");
    
            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }
    
            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(
                    path + File.separator + "IMG_"
                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");
    
            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
    
            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
    
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
    
            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
    
            // Set camera intent to file chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                    , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });
    
            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    
    
        }
    
        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }
    
        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                    String acceptType,
                                    String capture) {
    
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }
    
    }
```

Thanks